# glUniform3fv not working OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I'm working on a piece of code in OpenGL. 
I'm getting the following error message while trying to compile:

```
MyGLWidget.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void MyGLWidget::initializeGL()’:
MyGLWidget.cpp:30:38: error: cannot convert ‘glm::vec3 {aka glm::tvec3<float, (glm::precision)0u>}’ to ‘const GLfloat* {aka const float*}’ in argument passing
MyGLWidget.cpp:31:39: error: cannot convert ‘glm::vec3 {aka glm::tvec3<float, (glm::precision)0u>}’ to ‘const GLfloat* {aka const float*}’ in argument passing
```

I have declared these locations in MyGLWidget.h as follows:

```
    GLuint llumLoc, focusLoc;
```

And have initialize them in MyGLWidget.cpp as:

```
  llumLoc = glGetUniformLocation (program->programId(), "llumAmbient");
  focusLoc = glGetUniformLocation (program->programId(), "posFocus");
```

"llumAmbient" and "posFocus" are uniforms in my vertex shader:

```
uniform vec3 llumAmbient;
uniform vec3 posFocus;
```

I get the mentioned error message while trying to call the following code inside of MyGLWidget::initializeGL

```
glUniform3fv(llumLoc, 1, glm::vec3(0.2));
glUniform3fv(focusLoc, 1, glm::vec3(1.0));
```

Obviously, I've tried to follow the documentation at [www.opengl.org](http://www.opengl.org) and [glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00001.html](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00001.html), but I just can't see what's wrong with this code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give a pointer to the vector, not the vector itself. For example:

```
glm::vec3 v(1.0f);
glUniform3fv(focusLoc, 1, glm::value_ptr(&v[0]));
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that should be `glm::value_ptr(v)`

Comment: Perfect, that little correction did the trick. Working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Actually, I just found out today that there's a cleaner and more straight forward way. Simply:

```
glUniform3fv(focusLoc, 1, &v[0]);
```

No need to import *value_ptr*.